# IIS - PATH_TRANSLATED has additional spaces added to it, causing Suspicious Physical Path error

Tags: .net, iis

I have a .NET 4.7.2 app running on Windows Server 2016 on IIS. When a static image such as `/images/generic/facebook.png` is requested, I *sometimes* receive an `System.Web.HttpException` in `System.Web.Util.FileUtil#CheckSuspiciousPhysicalPath`.

I cannot reproduce anywhere but live, although our staging and test environments are identical. I think this is because of its intermittent nature rather than an aspect of the bug.

In the server parameters we have:

```
"PATH_INFO": "/images/generic/facebook.png",
  "PATH_TRANSLATED": "D:\\website\\images\\generic\\facebook.png                    ",
```

The `PATH_INFO` is the file being requested and the `PATH_TRANSLATED` is the path on the hard-drive. **Note the number of spaces added to the end**. This makes the path invalid for windows and that's why the path seems invalid.

If I add attack-vector-like query parameters to `facebook.png` then they are stripped off.

As this is occurring in the IIS PATH variables, I assume there is something wrong with the IIS configuration, which we do entirely through web.config.

**web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; style-src 'self' blob: 'unsafe-inline' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.googletagmanager.com; img-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com;" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Remove www" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
        <rule name="Remove Server header">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

### Least desirable solution

One solution appears to be adding:

`<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />`

Which would stop windows from throwing an error when the spaces were added but I would rather stop the spaces being appended in the first place.